# How to define an injective function from a set of sets of length $n$ to a set of sequences of length $n$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

> How to define an injective function from a set of sets of length $n$ to a set of sequences of length $n$ ($\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times...\times \mathbb N$)?

As far as i understand a set of sets of length $n$ is something like this (for example if $n=3$):
$$
\{\{1,2,3\}, \{5,7,9\}, \{100,345,500\},...,\}
$$
while a sequence of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\times \mathbb N $ is something like this:
$$
(1,2,3), (5,7,9), (100, 345, 500),...
$$
such that the main difference between the sets and sequences is that order matters in sequences while it doesn't in sets.

So I could say that if $S_n$ is a set of sets of length $n$ then let:
$$
f:S_n\to \mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times...\times \mathbb N
$$
such that we order the elements in each set $S_i, 1\le i\le n$ in increasing order. Intuitively I understand that $f$ is injective but how one really does prove it?

Comment: I assume you mean "How to define an injective function from *the* set of sets of length $n$ to *the* set of sequences of length $n$"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injectivity is best shown by exhibiting aright inverse.
First lets formalize your $f$.
Let $$\mathcal A=\{\,A\subseteq \Bbb N\mid |A|=n\,\}$$
be the set of length $n$ sets of natural numbers. Let
$$\mathcal B=\{\,b\mid b\text{ is a map }\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\Bbb N\,\}$$
be the set of length $n$ sequences of natural numbers.
For convenience, we consider the subset of injective maps
$$ \mathcal B_0:=\{\,b\in\mathcal B\mid b\text{ is injective}\,\}.$$

We can define $f\colon \mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ as follows:
Given $A\in\mathcal  A$, let $f(A)$ be given by $f(A)(k)=$ the $k$th smallest element of $A$, for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.Or recursively, $f(A)(k):=\min (A\setminus \{\,f(A)(j)\mid 1\le j<k\,\})$. One still has to show that this really defines a map, but I think there is a simpler way to begin with:

An alternative (and in this context more useful) way of describing $f$ is this: $\mathcal B$ is linearly ordered by lexical order: If $b_1,b_2\in\mathcal B$ with $b_1\ne b_2$, let $k=\min\{\,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\mid b_1(j)\ne b_2(j)\,\}$ and we say $b_1<b_2$ if $b_1(k)<b_2(k)$.
In fact, one verifies that this is a *well-order* on $\mathcal B$ (essentially because $<$ is a well-order on $\Bbb N$).
Now given $A\in\mathcal A$, the fact that $|A|=n$ tells us that there exists at least one bijection $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to A$, which can be viewed as an element  $b\in \mathcal B$, in fact it is clear that $b\in\mathcal B_0$.
This allows us to define $f\colon \mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ (or in fact even $f\colon \mathcal A\to\mathcal B_0$) by setting $$ f(A):=\min\{\,b\in\mathcal B_0\mid \operatorname{im}(b)=A\,\}.$$
Now in order to show that $f\colon \mathcal A\to\mathcal B_0$ is injective, we can simply exhibit a map $\mathcal B_0\to \mathcal A$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal A}$. Quite obviously. the straightforward map given by
$$ g(b):=\operatorname{im}(b)$$
does the trick.